# SSH Key Management with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am adding multiple servers on AWS and I want to have a better way of managing SSH keys than I have in the past.  I think AWS has a service built for this, through their IAM, management system, but I am not sure.

Is it possible to store one key in AWS and have all of the servers use that key for my account?  For example, if we have three users, I would like to give all of them access to the servers with their own keys - but they wouldn't have to setup a key on each server as we normally would.  If one of those users left the organization, I would like to disable their account to ensure the server isn't SSH'd into.

Is that possible, or am I misunderstanding AWS' key management possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to control SSH keys with IAM. In a very broad sense, SSH key is for shell access, IAM is for AWS API access.

There may be other ways to do what you are trying to accomplish. What I do is write few ansible scripts to automate this. Ansible makes it very simple to do these tasks using Ansible's ec2 module

Script 1: Launch an instance, add the users and their public keys

Script 2: Delete the user's account on all machines or move/remove the user's authorized_keys file

Like I said Ansible knows the inventory and deletes/disables the user on all machines.

Comment: I just looked up Ansible's website - the product starts at $5000/year!

Comment: It is free. You don't need Ansible Tower.

Comment: I don't see any free editions on their site. Are you referring to the free trial? I'm googling for open source versions now.

Comment: Just install Ansible using pip. Try it. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html